# win32 API SearchPath fails

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

The win32 API SearchPath API fails to find the "telnet.exe" binary path even though its present in system32.

However when I did a search for notepad.exe, with the same code it returns the file path. What puzzles me here is that both notepad.exe and telnet.exe lies in the same directory i.e C:\windows\system32.

This is the code I have written

```
char path[MAX_PATH] = {0};
LPSTR* ptr = NULL;

DWORD dwRet = SearchPathA(NULL, "telnet.exe",
    NULL, MAX_PATH, (LPSTR)path, ptr);
```

This would always return 0 and the GetLastError is 2 ( File not found)

Any idea what is happening here?

I am using windows 2008 R2 enterprise edition on an x64 machine

Thanks & Regards
Sunil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because you application is 32 bit and is being affected by the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Your application is not looking in `C:\Windows\System32` but is instead being redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWow64`.

`notepad.exe` exists in both `System32` and `SysWow64`, but `telnet.exe` only exists in `System32`.  So you application does not find it when it searches the path.

You can disable this behavior for your application by calling [Wow64DisasbleWow64FsRedirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  But note the warnings in the documentation links that indicate that this should only be disabled temporarily and then re-enabled.

Comment: *looking*, not *locking*.

Comment: Or pass the non-redirected System32 folder in the first parameter of `SearchPath()` using the `sysnative` alias, which the [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) does not redirect: "32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection."